# Lower bounds for determinant of $AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider all $m$ by $n$ matrices $A$ whose entries are $\pm 1$. Are there any lower bounds known for the $\max(\det(AA^T))$? Assume $m \leq n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide $n$ by $m$ and let the remainder be $r\ (0\le r<m)$. Write $A$ as an augmented matrix $[X_1|X_2|\cdots|X_k|Y]$, where each $X_j$ is square and $Y$ is $m\times r$. Then $AA^T=\sum_jX_jX_j^T+YY^T$ and hence $\det(AA^T)\ge\sum_j\det(X_jX_j^T)+\det(YY^T)=\sum_j\det(X_j)^2$. So, the maximum possible determinant of $AA^T$ must be at least $\lfloor\frac nm\rfloor$ times the square of the maximum possible determinant of $X_1$. This brings us back to the Hadamard maximal determinant problem.

You can find a number of papers on the lower bounds of the the maximal determinants of $\{-1,1\}$-matrices on the internet. E.g. see this very recent draft [paper by Brent, Osborn and Smith (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6817).